# Push rejected, fail to compile Node js app

Tags: node.js, heroku

heroku push failed because of Bcrypt failed to install via npm 
using Node : v13.9.0
Npm : v6.13.7

> 

```
gyp ERR! cwd
> /tmp/build_7e5a09f10b31aa1fe0f18582eece38dd/node_modules/grpc
>        gyp ERR! node -v v13.10.1
>        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.7
>        gyp ERR! not ok 
>        node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
>        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
> 

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>        npm ERR! errno 1
>        npm ERR! grpc@1.20.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
>        npm ERR! Exit status 1
>        npm ERR! 
>        npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.2 install script.
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is most likely that grpc version 1.20.2 is old enough that it does not support Node 13. I suggest using either a newer version of grpc or an older version of Node. Node 12 should work fine.

Comment: I tried with node 12 but it solve the problem so i should use a lastest version of grpc thanks ❤️